# Root view controller missing while making the Apple offered Page Control example to conform iOS5 SDK

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm a newbie for iOS developing, so my question might be a little juvenile.

I'm using a scroll view to implement a page control that have several subviews embedded and could swipe to change the subview appears on the screen. And when I browsing the iOS Developing Library, it was found that there is an Apple offered example for Page Control which was wrote on iOS4 could be bring to work. I downloaded it and tried to make it work on my project which is designed to run on iPhone with iOS5 but failed.

What the console always said after the project ran on iOS simulator is "**Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch**". Therefore I checked nearly all solutions on the web but nothing got work.

Here's the Apple offered Page Control example page : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html

And I've split my work into a smallest project and pushed it on GitHub. Here is the page :
https://github.com/WeZZard/PageControl

Anyone could help me?

Comment: I have got this problem solved. To remove the - (UIView *)view method from the root view controller implementation file will get it solved. It seems like that the root view controller's -(UIView *)view method returns a wrong value after been implemented in this file which would get the storyboard's initialization goes wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, if your using storyboard, make sure on your first view controller you have "Is initial view controller" ticked.

Comment: Thanks. But I think I just have that option ticked yet. And what made me confused was that the console wouldn't report any error if I get a project ran only with an empty view controller specified. I create all projects from the single view template which have "Is initial view controller" ticked by default.

Answer (score 0):

In the sample code appdelgate.m file

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSString *nibTitle = @"PadContent";
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        nibTitle = @"PhoneContent";
    }
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibTitle owner:self options:nil];

    [self.window addSubview:self.contentController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

here you see that one is loading different nib(iPad and iPhone ) for different devices.

normally in projects you see

```
    [self.window addSubview:self.rootviewcontroller.view];
```

but the only difference is

```
    [self.window addSubview:self.contentController.view];
```

and it is loading the nib using the current nib..(*[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibTitle owner:self options:nil];*)

so the project is same as any other project

Comment: I didn't totally copy all the code from the sample code especially the -(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching: method because that I want to use storyboard to manage my view controllers and view hierarchies but not Nib file. I've got the point that [self.window addSubview:self.rootViewController.view] or self.window.rootViewController = self.rootViewController is the key to solve some issues also titled root view controller missing by checking solutions on the web but it doesn't work for mine... It's strange... It might be also occurred in some iOS4-app-upgrade-to-iOS5-app cases.